# Disable your own notification when sharing Sharepoint/Onedrive site

Tags: office-365, share

I was wondering if there was a way to disable the email notification we get when sharing a file or site to another user?

I get that the end user should receive a notification. If I share something with `USER1`, I already know, because I just did it myself. So I would like to disable this email.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a single email with USER1 in `To` and you in `CC`, AFAIK. So it's safe to think there is no way to exclude yourself.

Simple Outlook rule at your side will be much faster solution than hoping that Microsoft will make the process divided and controllable.